# How to access fields from an inner query?

Tags: soql

I have two custom objects.  One parent, one child.  I am using an inner query to obtain records.

```
for(objectA__c obA: [select id, myfieldA__c, (select id, myfieldB__c from objectB__r) from objectA__c)]{

//Perform some code here


}
```

I am receiving 'Invalid foreign key relationship when I attempt to use the following:

```
obA.objectB__r.myfieldB__c
```

How do I reference myfieldB__c on objectB__c????

I've looked at documentation on standard objects and it makes sense but I can't seem to get this to work on custom objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The inner query return a list of records so you need to iterate throughout them taking into account how to process the records if multiple records are in the returned result. What to do depends on your use case

```
for(objectA__c obA: [select id, myfieldA__c, (select id, myfieldB__c from objectB__r) from objectA__c)]{

   For(ObjectB__c b : oba.ObjectB__r){
      //Access the field from the record taking into account there could be multiple results in this loop
      PROPERTY/FIELD/ETC = b.myfieldb__c;
   }


}
```

If however ChildB is a detail of a master, no need to do the inner select as you can simply pull the field via

```
objecA__c.ObjectB__r.myfield__c
```

but your query would be different:

```
[Select ID, objectb__r.myfieldb__c From Objecta__c]
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense and both ways work great.  Thanks for the examples.