# How to loop trough subquery relations [MAP] and put all in 1 [MAP]

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, map, subquery

I have a before insert trigger where Relatietype__c is a junction object on contact and account. I need to compare these with a 3rd object Huishouden__c with the Huishouden__c.name field which is a combination of string contact.MailingPostalCode + contact.mailingstreet + account.name and is a lookup field on Relatietype__c that needs to be filled on insertion.

I placed the relations in a map. I currently can loop trough accountIdMap with the first relation. I want to loop trough all the children and place them in the huishoudenMap.How to achieve this?

Trigger:

```
public class  RelatieTriggerHandler {
public static void onBeforeInsert(Relatie__c[] rcs) {
    // EXECUTE BEFORE INSERT LOGIC  
    Map<Id,Account> accountIdMap; 
    List<Id> setOfId = new List<Id>(); 
    for(Relatie__c rc : rcs) { 
        if(rc.Relatietype__c == 'Lid') {
        setOfId.add(Rc.Account__c); 
        }
    } 
    accountIdMap = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Relatienummer__c, (SELECT id, Contactpersoon__c, Contactpersoon__r.MailingPostalCode ,Contactpersoon__r.mailingstreet, Account__c,Account__r.name  FROM Relatie_Contacten__r WHERE Account__c in :setOfId)
                                       FROM Account 
                                       WHERE Id in :setOfId]); 

    map<Id,String> huishoudenMap = new map<Id,String>();
    for(Account  acc : accountIdMap.values()) {
        if(accountIdMap.size()>0){
    huishoudenMap.put(acc.Relatie_Contacten__r[0].Account__c, acc.Relatie_Contacten__r[0].Contactpersoon__r.MailingPostalCode + acc.Relatie_Contacten__r[0].Contactpersoon__r.mailingstreet +' '+ acc.Relatie_Contacten__r[0].Account__r.name );
     }
```

}

I want to achieve something similar to:

```
    for(Account  acc : accountIdMap.values()) {
            if(accountIdMap.size()>0){
 if(accountIdMap.acc.Relatie_Contacten__r.size()>0){
        huishoudenMap.put(acc.Relatie_Contacten__r.Account__c, acc.Relatie_Contacten__r.Contactpersoon__r.MailingPostalCode + acc.Relatie_Contacten__r.Contactpersoon__r.mailingstreet +' '+ acc.Relatie_Contacten__r.Account__r.name );
 }
         }
```

BACKGROUND INFO
household is like a membership for a home. If there is no membership combination of contact.MailingPostalCode + contact + account, a new memership needs to be created. In the end the oldes contact of this  membership/houselhold will be the main holder, checkbox= true on Relatie__c and all other household members checkbox= false

Comment: You need to loop through the results of the subquery. This question has been asked before, try taking a look at the answer to this question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81120/how-to-access-fields-from-an-inner-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access fields from an inner query?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81120/how-to-access-fields-from-an-inner-query)

Comment: @Kyle I had a look at your example but this is a map where I can get the values with accountIdMap.values() so I don't see the solution in the example you gave. Maybe you can clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please bear with me here, as I *think* I understand what you're going for but may have missed something.

You have a junction object `Relatie__c` between `Account` and `Contact`. You have an entirely separate object `Huishouden__c` (household?) that has a sort of composite identifier built out of values from both the Contact and the Account that are joined by a `Relatie__c` record. In this trigger on `Relatie__c`, you want to do something to your `Huishouden__c` records by looking them up through this composite identifier. Am I with you so far?

Let me try going through the code here.

```
public class HuishoudenTriggerHandler {
```

The name confused me for a bit. I'd call this `RelatieTriggerHandler` since it's running on that object.

```
public static void onBeforeInsert(Relatie__c[] rcs) {
    // EXECUTE BEFORE INSERT LOGIC  
    Map<Id,Account> accountIdMap; 
    List<Id> setOfId = new List<Id>(); 
    for(Relatie__c rc : rcs) { 
        if(rc.Relatietype__c == 'Lid') {
        setOfId.add(Rc.Account__c); 
        }
    }
```

Up to here, this makes total sense. We're collecting the Accounts of new `Relatie__c` records in a set.

```
    accountIdMap = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Relatienummer__c, (SELECT id, Contactpersoon__c, Contactpersoon__r.MailingPostalCode ,Contactpersoon__r.mailingstreet, Account__c,Account__r.name  FROM Relatie_Contacten__r WHERE Account__c in :setOfId)
                                       FROM Account 
                                       WHERE Id in :setOfId]);
```

This subquery can be simplified a little bit. You do not need the `WHERE Account__c in :setOfId` clause in the subquery, because the subquery is inherently limited to the records linked to a specific Account in the returned data set. You also probably don't need to include `Account__c,Account__r.name` in the subquery fields - you can query for `Name` in the parent query.

```
    map<Id,String> huishoudenMap = new map<Id,String>();
    for(Account acc : accountIdMap.values()) {
        if(accountIdMap.size()>0){
    huishoudenMap.put(acc.Relatie_Contacten__r[0].Account__c, acc.Relatie_Contacten__r[0].Contactpersoon__r.MailingPostalCode + acc.Relatie_Contacten__r[0].Contactpersoon__r.mailingstreet +' '+ acc.Relatie_Contacten__r[0].Account__r.name );
     }
```

Your question seems to be "How do I add to the map an entry for each `Relatie__c` record for this Account, rather than just the first ([0]) entry?"

You can nest another `for` loop in here, and it would look like this. Note that I am removing the inner `if` statement. It will always evaluate to `true` and hence is not useful.

```
    for(Account acc : accountIdMap.values()) {
        for (Relatie__c r : acc.Relatie_Contacten__r) {
            huishoudenMap.put(acc.Id,
                             r.Contactpersoon__r.MailingPostalCode + 
                             r.Contactpersoon__r.MailingStreet +
                             ' '+ 
                             acc.Name);
        }
    }
```

I think that'll do what you're looking for. Note, though, that if the combination of `MailingPostalCode` + `MailingStreet` + `Account.Name` is not unique within each Account (meaning you have two associated Contacts with the same values in those fields), your Map will only contain a single entry for all of those Contacts sharing the same values.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! As I am a beginner I missed a important part, but hey I wont delete this time. Actually Account__c is a lookup field value on Relatie__c that gets filled on a new insert on Relatie__c which is the ID of Huishouden__c if existent so the reason to get  Account__c is to do check if there is an Huishouden__c exiting already if not Ill be inserting a new Huishouden__c. Sorry for the confusion. Account__r.name is to use as a string. Ps. Totally right on the name of the trigger.

Comment: Sorry Thomas, I don't completely follow you. To help clarify, can you give us the API names of all of the lookup fields on `Relatie__c` and which object each one connects to?

Comment: Account__c = Account , Contactpersoon__c = contact, Huishouden__c =Id.name =r.Contactpersoon__r.MailingPostalCode + r.Contactpersoon__r.MailingStreet + ' '+  acc.Name   Hope this clarifies.

Comment: I think so. I understand why you need the Account Id and Name. Just remember that as you're iterating over the `Relatie__c` objects that are *children* of an Account, you *already have* the Account's Id and Name - they're fields on the Account from your outer `for` loop. So you don't need to get them from the `Relatie__c` record itself.

Comment: I think you pointed me in the right direction Thanks. I also updated my question with some background info.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with it and working through the question. Hope you're able to get it sorted out!